# Error evaluating Javascript datastructure using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dictionary

I have the following stored as a javascript variable:

```
"{'Headings': 
    [{'name': 'Behavior', 'majorTopic': 'N', 'vote': {'down': 1, 'up': 1}},
     {'name': 'Brain Mapping', 'majorTopic': 'N'}, 
     {'name': 'Evoked Potentials', 'majorTopic': 'N'}
 ]}"
```

such that the type of the variable is a string. 
I am trying to evaluate the string to get a dictionary such that:

```
{"headings":[{"name":behavior,'majorTopic':"N", 'vote':{'down':1,'up':1}}]}
```

But when I attempt to use eval(variable) or JSON.parse(variable), I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at eval For eval
```

and

```
VM529:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` For the JSON.parse function.
```

I believe the error pertains to the nesting of the vote dictionary with upvotes and downvotes,
but when I evaluate a nested statement like this independently, I am getting no issues.

How could I keep the nested vote tab while evaluating this statement?

Comment: your json does not pass validation test from http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use double quotes in your JSON string. Other than that it is OK, should parse without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a valid json:

```
{
"Headings": [{
    "name": "Behavior",
    "majorTopic": "N",
    "vote": {
        "down": 1,
        "up": 1
    }
}, {
    "name": "Brain Mapping",
    "majorTopic": "N"
}, {
    "name": "Evoked Potentials",
    "majorTopic": "N"
}]
}
```